# RDP - End session without losing screen resolution

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

I have a Virtual Machine hosted elsewhere in the world.

What I want to do is to disconnect from this RDP session without:

- Windows locking automatically
- Screen resolution changing

I've solved the first issue of the windows locking by running this `.bat` file to end the session:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3" %%s in ('query user %USERNAME%') do (
  %windir%\System32\tscon.exe %%s /dest:console
)
```

However, when I run a script remotely to check the screen resolution, it drops down to `1614x834`.

How can I explicitly set `1920x1080`?

Answer (score -1):

Try that:

1. Install software Remote desktop in your Virtual Machine
2. After running that command, remote to Virtual Machine with that installed software and then adjust the screen resolution to 1920x1080

Can exit the software when the configuration is complete, It does not affect the process

This worked for my project :3